# Getting the text of the current form

Tags: c#, datagrid

I want to do a list filtering by the text of the current form.
I have a list of Tasks and i want to display on my DataGrid only the tasks where the Username attribute value is the same as my Form's text.

I have tried this:

```
foreach (Task a in tasks)
        {
            if(a.Username == ProgForm.ActiveForm.Text )
            tdt.Rows.Add(a.Id, a.Name, a.Description, a.IsSolved, a.IsTested, a.Username);

        }
```

For example if my Form's Text is "user1" , I want my DataGrid to display only the Tasks with the Username "user1".

If I comment this line of code

```
if(a.Username == ProgForm.ActiveForm.Text )
```

The DataGrid will display all the tasks, so there's no problem there. I don't know how to do the filtering.

Thank you.

Edit:

Found the solution:

Replace this:

```
if(a.Username == ProgForm.ActiveForm.Text )
```

With this:

```
if(a.Username == this.Text )
```

Comment: What is appearing in the debugger for those two values? What is the "text" for the current form?

Comment: a.Username is "user1" but ProgForm.ActiveForm is null. I don't know how to get the text from my current form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
tasks
    .Where(a => a.Username == this.Text)
    .ForEach(a => 
        tdt.Rows.Add(a.Id, a.Name, a.Description, a.IsSolved, a.IsTested, a.Username)
    );
```

Comment: This would work, except it has nothing to do with the question of why ActiveForm is null.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yes, have just seen that comment.

Comment: The filtering would be done right if i put the actual value between double quotes. I'm not sure using the ActiveForm is the right way to go.

Comment: If you just change the `ProgForm.ActiveForm.Text` to `this.Text` it would work perfectly.